# Understanding URL patterns in django

Tags: python, django, url

What does this URL pattern mean?

```
url(r'^(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', views.confirm, name='confirm-page'),
)
```

How can I activate it?

Comment: ... and name='confirm-page' used to set name for this uri. It used in redirects, templates to provide <a href={% url 'confirm-page' 75%}... and etc.

Answer (score 4):

A request to `/75/` or `/3/` would call the function `views.confirm(itemnum='75')` or `views.confirm(itemnum='3')`.

The variable `itemnum` can hold any number.

You can read more about url dispatcher [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Answer (score 4):

Let's see:

- `^` means the beginning of a string
- `(?P<itemnum>\d+)` is a [named saving group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) that in your case matches 1 or more digits in a row. The captured part of the url will be passed as a keyword argument to your `views.confirm` function:

  ```
  def confirm(request, itemnum=None):
      print itemnum
      ...
  ```
- `$` means the end of a string

Example: `2013` will be captured from `http://mydomain.com/2013/`.

Comment: I would like to add this [URL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict) for reference